# Interrupt handling in linux

Tags: linux, hardware, interrupt

Can you explain me how `interrupts` is handling in linux in general? I'm using `gentoo 12`. As I understand `HW IRQ` is just electrical signal from a specific hardware to a processor itself. I dont understand, how does processor is distinguishes interrupts coming from differents hardware?

Let we install a new hardware. Obvviously it is not know what a specific electric impulse will came to a process from this hardware. So it's not clear how processor change a specific interrupt handler for this interrupt.

Comment: This question is probably more appropriate for cs.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1):

The interrupts are handled by linux kernel. BUS interrupts will often share the same HW IRQ, but the kernel will be able to sort them up based on their data and pass them to particular device driver.

Answer (score 1):

Dpeends on the hardware. e.g. PCI devices provides a standard way to query each device of what it is, what interrupt it wants to use, and then a proper driver/interupt handler can be installed for it.

There's interfaces such as [ACPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Configuration_and_Power_Interface) that the hardware and the operating system must comply with to communicate and configure the hardware, USB devices provides a discovery service that must be completed whenever a new device is attached and so on.

So yes, the operating system very much know when you attach a device and what to do about it if it can.

Some hardware platforms might not provide such means, in which case the supported hardware must be hardcoded into the operating system (or more commonly read from a configuration file), in which case you indeed cannot just attach a new piece of hardware to it and expect it to just plug and play (examples of this would be the [device tree](http://www.devicetree.org/Main_Page) used on many embedded platforms)